# show only specific glyphs using opentypejs

Tags: css, fonts

I am using opentype.js to extract glyphs from google font(Poppin). Currently It shows all the glyphs nicely. but i want only the character and numbers only. such as "A,B,C and 1,2,3 etc.
Is there any way to show only specific items from glyphs table?

thanks in advance

Comment: Any idea regarding this matter???

Answer (score 1):

`font.stringToGlyphs('ABC')` or `font.getPaths(chars, 0, 90, 100)` would return only selected glyphs.

Use e.g `font.stringToGlyphs()` if you need to get glyph properties like sidebearings, unicode etc.
`font.getPaths()` will return path data (commands).

```js
let preview = document.querySelector("#svgPreview"); 
let chars = "ABCD0123";
let output ='';
// opentype.js accepts woff, ttf and otf
let fontFile = "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v19/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1xlEw.woff";

opentype.load(fontFile, function (err, font) {
  if (!err) {
    //get glyphs as object
    let glyphs = font.stringToGlyphs(chars);
    console.log(glyphs)
    
    //get glyphs pathdata for previewing
    let paths = font.getPaths(chars, 0, 90, 100);
    paths.forEach(function(path, i){
      output +=path.toSVG(2)
    });
    preview.innerHTML = output;
    let vb = preview.getBBox();
    preview.setAttribute('viewBox',[0, 0, (vb.width+vb.x), 120].join(' ') )
    console.log(paths);
    
  } else {
    console.log("Font could not be loaded: " + err);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opentype.js@latest/dist/opentype.min.js"></script>
<style>
svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height:10em;
}
</style>
<svg id="svgPreview" viewBox="0 0 1000 100">
</svg>
```