# How to convert text to SVG path

Tags: html, svg, path

I downloaded a font name san francisco font. I want to convert each letter to svg font. I found this code on w3school

```
<svg height="210"
width="400">
<path d="M150 0 L75 
200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

[Link to site](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp)

I think letters are more complicated to make than a simple triangle shape.
I want to know how to convert a text to svg path

Comment: try sites like https://vectormagic.com

Comment: You can use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) and a lot of the other vector graphics applikations. In Inkscape, select the text and in the menu pick Path > Object to Path.

Comment: If you need to create paths from text dynamically, you could use [opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js). See also this question: [show only specific glyphs using opentypejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627294/show-only-specific-glyphs-using-opentypejs/71288023)

Comment: What have you tried so far ?